# Unexpected Event Behavior When Using VB6 with COM Interop (C#)

Tags: c#, com, vb6, interop

We are using a COM Interop (C#) to allow for a VB6 application to send data to a server.  Once the server receives the data, the managed code will raise a DataSent event.  This event is only fired after a correlation ID is returned to the original caller.

About 1% of the time, we've encountered VB6 executing the raised event before finishing the function that originally sent the data.

Using the following code:

```
' InteropTester.COMEvents is the C# object '
Dim WithEvents m_ManagedData as InteropTester.COMEvents

Private Sub send_data()

   Set m_ManagedData = new COMEvents
   Dim id as Integer
   ' send 5 to using the managed interop object '
   id = m_ManagedData.SendData(5)
   LogData "ID " & id & " was returned"
   m_correlationIds.Add id

End Sub

Private Sub m_ManagedData_DataSent(ByVal sender as Variant, ByVal id as Integer)
   LogData "Data was successfully sent to C#"
   ' check if the returned ID is in the m_correlationIds collection goes here'
End Sub
```

We can verify that the id is returned with a value when we call `m_ManagedData.SendData(5)`, but the logs then show that the `m_ManagedData_DataSent` is occasionally called before `send_data` ends.

How is possible for VB6 to access the Message Loop to know that the `DataSent` event was raised before exiting `send_data()`?  We are not calling `DoEvents` and everything within VB6 is synchronous.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling that the COM event is raised faster than the result of the method call being marshaled back to VB6. How much of a time difference are you seeing between the 2 calls to `LogData`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We're seeing the time difference within a millisecond.